# Worshiping planets a vedic tradition or Puranic tradition?

Tags: vedas, puranas, worship

Is Nava Graha worship a Vedic tradition or a puranic tradition? Are there any references to Nava Graha worship in Vedas?

Comment: Padma Purana mentions methods of worshiping Planets.

Comment: @Shyam Kumar..I covered only the "Navagraha in Vedas" part of ur question..Do u want any info on Navagraha Puja in Purana as well?..I assumed that u already know about this..but i may be wrong..so if u want that info i can update my answer..

Comment: I am of the view that Navagraha worship is mainly associated with later vedic period. One of the reasons for the this assumption is that none of the Hindu temples that had an existence of a few centuries couldn't find Navagraha idols or for that matter any sort of  Navagraha worship over there.I even doubt (I am not quite sure of it) that we could hardly come across any reference of Navagraha worship in the two Hindu epics.,VIZ, Ramayana and Maha Bharath.I would like to know your views in this subject.

Answer (score 6):

There are a bunch of Vedic mantras  together called as the "Navagraha Suktam" which is considered to be a hymn dedicated to the Navagrahas.

Although it's called the **Navagraha Suktam** and the mantras are accepted as mantras related to the Navagrahas by authoritative Hindu organizations but the explicit mention of Navagraha is never to be found in that hymn.

In any case,the following are a few mantras from that hymn.

The mantra that is attributed to Surya in that hymn is:

> [image]
>
> With  the Light   of  Truth   in  space   advancing,  determining life    and death,  borne   in  his golden  chariot he  comes,  Savitar,    God who gazes   upon    the worlds. (Rig    Veda    1.35.2  ;   Taitt.  Sam.3.4.11.2a)
>
> a̱ gni ṁ d ū ̱ta ṁ v ṛ ̍ ṇ īmahe ̱ hot ā ̍ra ṁ vi ̱śvave ̍dasam | a
> ̱sya ya ̱jñasya ̍ su ̱kratum ̎ |
>
> We    choose  Agni    as  our messenger,  the herald, master  of  all wealth. Well    skilled in  this    our sacrifice.  (RigVeda    1.12.1; Taitt.  Sam.    2.5.8.5)
>
> ye ṣāmī śe ̍ paśu ̱pati ̍ ḥpa śūn āṁ catu ̍ ṣpad ām uta ca
> ̍ dvipadām | niṣkrī ̍to ̱’ya ṁ ya ̱jñiya ̍ ṁ bhā ̱game ̍tu r
> ā ̱yas-poṣā ̱ yaja ̍m ānasya santu ||
>
> Which creatures   does    the Lord    of  creatures   rule:—  both    the four    footed  and birds.  May He, being
> propitiated,  accept  His sacrificial share,  may abundance   of  wealth  come    to  the sacrificer. (Taitariya Samhita. 3;1;4d)

Similarly the mantra for Soma(Moon) is :

> om  aapyaa yasva  sametu tay vishvata: soma  vrushN iyam | bhavaa
> vaajasya sangathay | apsumesomo  abraveedantar vish vaani bhesha  jaa
> | agnincha  vishvasham bhuvamaapashcha vishva b heshajee: |  gouree
> mimaaya salilaani  takshatyeka padee dvipade e  saa  chatushpadee |
> ashTaapadee  navapadee babhoovushee   sahasra  aksharaa paramay vyoman
> ||   om  adhi devataa pratyadhi devataa sahitaaya somaaya  nama:

& similar mantras are there for each of the remaining 7 grahas.

You can read the whole suktam from [here.](http://www.bharatiweb.com/English/Navagraha%20Sooktam%20Eng%20v1.pdf).For english translations you can refer to [Hindupedia.com.](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Navagraha_Suktham).And, for the Nakshatras we too have similar Veda mantras contained in the [Nakshtra Suktam](http://www.bharatiweb.com/wp-content/uploads/Nakshatra-Sooktam-Eng-v1.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer.

There is this passage that talks about ways to keep heavenly bodies pleased.

> **Grahas in Mahabharata**
>
> Markandeya answered, ‘There are three kinds of purity, viz., purity in
>   speech, purity in deed, and purity achieved by use of water. He that
>   has recourse to these three kinds of purity, attains, without doubt,
>   to heaven. That Brahmana who adoreth the goddess Sandhya in the
>   morning and the evening, and who recites meditatively the sacred
>   goddess Gayatri who is the mother of the Vedas, sanctified by the
>   latter, is freed from all his sins. Even if he accepts in gift the
>   entire earth with her oceans, he doth not, on that account, suffer the
>   least unhappiness. **And those heavenly bodies in the sky including
>   the sun that may be inauspicious and hostile towards him soon becomes
>   auspicious and favorable towards him in consequence of these acts of
>   his, while those stars that are auspicious and favorable become more
>   auspicious and favorable in consequence of such conduct of his.**’

Mahabharata, Vana Parva, Section CLXLIX

Comment: How does this answer the question?OP is asking whether Navagraha worship is mentioned in Veda itself or it sprouted from the Puranas.

Comment: I admitted that this is only a partial answer. I didn't claim that my answer fully answers the question. The Mahabharata passage suggests that keeping heavenly deities pleased is part of the Vedic heritage.

Comment: Such things should me mentioned at many places in Puranas also..So shud we take those as proofs of that Navagraha Pujan is as per Vedic directives?

Comment: It's up to the reader whether this thing should be taken as proof or not.

Comment: If Navagraha Pujan is mentioned in Vedas only that qualifies for a proof....Take the concept of  Yugas for ex..according to ur logic "yUgas are mentioned in MB that means Yugas must be a Vedic thing"..I'm amazed..anyways let's leave it..